# How to secure web api to validate openid token generated by Client application?

Tags: c#, .net, .net-core, oauth-2.0, openid-connect

OpenId Connect configuration in start up.cs file of **Client app** :

```
services.AddAuthentication(options =>
            {
                options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultChallengeScheme = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
                options.DefaultSignInScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
            })
            .AddCookie()

            .AddOpenIdConnect(options =>
            {
                options.ClientId = azureAdConfig.ClientId;
                options.ClientSecret = azureAdConfig.ClientSecret;
                options.Authority = string.Format(com/, azureAdConfig.Tenant);
                options.ResponseType = OpenIdConnectResponseType.CodeIdToken;
                options.Resource = azureAdConfig.ResourceURI_Graph;
                options.Events = new AuthEvents(azureAdConfig, connectionStringsConfig);
            });
```

I want to pass the token to web api.

> But how to secure web api and validate the token in api project?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I agree that most docs seem to focus on the web app scenario. Assuming you are using .Net Core there as well, for APIs it is a case of using the features of this package:

- Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.JwtBearer

```
services
.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
.AddJwtBearer(options =>
{
})
```

For a working example see resources below -the code can be written the same way with any Authorization Server:

- [Code](https://github.com/curityio/dotnet-api-jwt-validation)
- [Doc](https://curity.io/resources/guides/api/netcore/)

**AZURE AD TOKENS**

These have some specific requirements. The thing to avoid in custom APIs is JWTs with a nonce field in the JWT header, since these are only meant to be used by Microsoft's own APIs

My [blog post](https://authguidance.com/2017/12/01/azure-ad-spa-code-sample/) has some details on how to get round this, by registering a logical API service to represent one or more APIs, then exposing your own API scopes.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. is it mandatory to get Service Principal created in Azure AD to get admin consented in order to get valid token for API resource?

Comment: Added some info on Azure AD tokens to my answer

Comment: One thing I don't understand is how to be sure the JWT Bearer token is not fabricated or faked. Or am I missing something here?

Comment: @WilkovanderVeen You can validate the audience and issuer of the token in the events to make sure the token is generated by trusted party and is for trusted audience.